# Query String: Replace the Same Text Multiple Times

Tags: regex, .htaccess, replace, query-string, dokuwiki

Background:
I recently changed in a DokuWiki installation every string which contains a specific product name to another. Now I have to redirect hard-coded links to the new URL.

The URLs look like:

```
past:    example.com/wiki/doku.php?id=sales:producta:descr:producta
present: example.com/wiki/doku.php?id=sales:productb:descr:productb
```

Issue:
I should replace the string `producta` to `productb`. This string can occur several times in a URL. Therefore it should be replaced regardless the number of occurences.

I found several ways to replace a unique string. But I need to replace every single occurrance of this string in the URL. A working replacement before the question mark ist possible, but i didn't found a solution to manipulating the querystring like this.

Is there a way to achieve this replacement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's quite tricky, but it can be done. Try adding this to the `.htaccess` file in your web document root folder (often `public_html` or `htdocs`):

```
Options -Multiviews
RewriteEngine On
# If the query string contains producta, capture it to %1
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(.+?producta.*)
# ... and bring it down to the url, temporarily inserting @@
RewriteRule ^(.+) $1@@%1? [DPI]
# Rewrite product a to product b but only if @@ is in the string
RewriteRule ^([^@]+@@.*)producta(.*) $1productb$2 [N] 
# Remove @@
RewriteRule ^([^@]+)@@(.*) $1?$2 [L]
```

This assumes that mod_rewrite is **both** installed **and** activated for `.htaccess` files. 
If you are not sure, to check if mod_rewrite is even installed, look at the list of installed modules in the output of `phpinfo();`
By default, mod_rewrite is not enabled for `.htaccess` files. If you are managing your own server, open `httpd.conf`
and make sure that the webroot directory block contains one of these lines: `AllowOverride FileInfo` or `AllowOverride All`

Comment: Wow! Functioned instantly. Thank you for your grate support. An unimportant question: Is there a way to show the replacement in the URL too?

Comment: Thank you. The R redirection seems to be inoperative. The url changed but de page doesn't load und stay on the opened page. But this is irrelevant. I have a major problem: Also URLs without querystrings will be redirected, like this: http://www.example.com/there/sales/producta/version.txt internally to http://www.example.com/there/sales/productb/version.txt. Because the condition only will be considered by the first Rule. Therefore I limited the Rules to one directory like this:RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/(wiki)(/.*)? above every rule. It doesn't make a proper impression. Any suggestions?

Comment: You are absolutely right, I forgot to ensure that producta=>productb only happens to these urls with the query string. Done now (see the comments in the tweaked solution). Can you please tell me if that fixes it?

Comment: Terrific, glad to hear it!